# using visual studio #pragma to make project high priority

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to test my project in high priority because the wall-clock timing I have in code seemed to be too long. I have already tried setting my `.exe` to run in high priority through the command line. It brought back the same time. Someone suggested that I use visual studio's `#pragma` to make it high priority, however I cannot find how to do that.

Note, my current project is single thread.
Is there any other way?

specific project is: timing sound initialization of soundcard (digital->analog) and DAQ (analog->digital). It's taking `1.1013` to `0.998` seconds, and I'm going to need it to be more precise because I'm using the DAQ to acquire data of a process that only takes around `10ms`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a certain function in your software requires to run in high priority, use the Windows functions **SetThreadPriority** or **SetPriorityClass**.

As soon as running at high priority is not required anymore, your software should revert back to normal priority. Do not try to keep your application running always and generally as "high priority". This would be hostile behavior :)

More information at:
[msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685100.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685100.aspx)